# Request fails from my web application when refreshing the Browser (Firefox). When starting new tab this issue do not happen

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, dll, iis-7.5

My application make a request to a .dll and set my extension.
[My application is a call control application. All operations are achieved, like make call from extension,set my extension, etc using request to dll(C++)]

My issue is, I make a get request from the application using javascript to the dll as follows
GET http://192.168.XX.XX/iq/VpWebExt.dll?ACTION=GETEXT&EXT=5042&REDIRECT=NO&now=1397018694640

I get the XML response successfully when i load my application in new tab. But When I reload the page, if the application try to set the extension using the above mentioned request, it does not return the XML response.

Below is the piece of code in my web app which makes the request. I get status code as "0" and httpObj.responseText as empty.

```
var httpObj;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
httpObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
httpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

httpObj.open("GET", httpUrl, false);
httpObj.send();
if ( httpObj.status == 200 )
{ httpResult = httpResult + httpObj.responseText;
}
else
{
alertAppConsole("httpObj.status = " + httpObj.status);
}
```

---

This issue happens only in "FireFox". In other browsers like IE or chrome where I tested I don't face the issue.

Also to I need to mention, when I deploy in my local machine(win 7, IIS 7.5) this issue do not happen at all.

When I deploy in my client machine (Windows server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5) this issue occurs.

Comment: I found that When I do Ctrl + F5 this issue does not appear. When I do a normal reload alone it occurs.

Comment: The difference is that in Ctrl + F5 it clears forces a reload of the page by clearing cache, so that's somewhere to start.

Comment: It could also be returning a cached response. IIS is partial to IE sometimes.